# Having trouble with GridSearchCV.fit displaying TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand this error.

```
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
 84 
 85  

 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It seems to have stemmed from another error listed below.

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am trying to fit training data which is within a pandas dataframe with each row containing a numpy array. The associated labels are integer values within a pandas dataframe as well. Please find the steps leading up to error below.

```
for target in targetList:
   criterion_opts = np.array(['entropy', 'gini'])
   n_estimators_opts = [50, 100, 150, 200, 400, 500]
   param_grid = dict(criterion = criterion_opts, n_estimators = n_estimators_opts)
   cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
   grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid, scoring='roc_auc')
   X_train = pd.DataFrame({'Morgan Fingerprints':Xtrain[f"{target}"]})
   y_train = ytrain[f"{target}"]
   grid.fit(np.array(X_train), y_train)
   #print(f"The best params for {target} are: " + grid.best_params_)
```

Please find some examples of the items stored in the instance and label dataframes below.

```
   Morgan Fingerprints
435   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...
1830  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
[2284 rows x 1 columns]

435     1
1830    0
Name: activity_class, Length: 2284, dtype: object
```

Edit: So whilst I was recreating some code to reproduce the error it seems I have located the source of the error. When I pass in Xtrain as a list of numpy arrays then the GridSearchCV.fit() has no issues. However, when I convert Xtrain to a Pandas dataframe then pass it to fit then the issue pops up.

The code below should reproduce the error. If you remove the transformation of Xtrain to a dataframe the problem should be removed. Can anyone explain why this is? I understand fit is expecting an array but I thought passing a dataframe containing an array should be okay?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train = pd.DataFrame({'Morgan Fingerprints':[np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]), np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), 
np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]),  np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]),  np.array([1, 
0,1, 1, 0, 1])]})
y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

criterion_opts = np.array(['entropy', 'gini'])
n_estimators_opts = [50, 100, 150, 200, 400, 500]
param_grid = dict(criterion = criterion_opts, n_estimators = 
n_estimators_opts)
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid, 
cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')
grid.fit(np.array(X_train), y_train)
#print(f"The best params for {target} are: " + grid.best_params_)
```

Edit #2: So it seems I have finally managed to fix this problem. First I appended the values of the dataframe to a list. However, this presented an issue where fit was expecting an array of dim 2 and got dim 3 (I assume this was because the individual arrays were nested within a list?). This was then resolved by creating a "final" Xtrain where I just extracted the arrays from the nested lists and used these as the individual training instances for the model.

Comment: Please update your question with the **full** error trace - see how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered as per my edits. Would appreciate if someone could provide me some wisdom as to why this happened.